# Unexpected data in table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that inserts or replaces data in table and it works fine on localhost, but on real host it behaves strange.

The query:

```
REPLACE INTO sessions (
    user_id, authorization_token, authorization_token_expires, refresh_token, refresh_token_expires
) VALUES (
    :user_id, :authorization_token, :authorization_token_expires, :refresh_token, :refresh_token_expires
);
```

The problem is when I insert a new row into the table it inserts a row with user_id = 0 and updates it with every insert/replace query. Since this works normal on local, I suppose that something wrong with server/DBMS settigns.

**EDIT**

Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions`

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `authorization_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `authorization_token_expires` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `refresh_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `refresh_token_expires` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems like problem is with `pdo->lastInsertId();`. I have a function that inserts user in my `users` table and returns lastInsertId. If I `var_dump()` this function result looks like `string(1) "1"`. If I transfer result of function to function that inserts row in my `sessions` table I get strange result I described above. But if I transfer simple string like "1" to function that inserts sessions I get correct behavior. Definetly have no idea what's going on :/

Comment: If you suspect that this is an issue with your RDBMS, then wouldn't it make sense to tell us what DBMS you actually use and what settings you chose?

Comment: Please compare table schemes on local and remote host. Look as table have not auto_increment id

Comment: "it inserts a row with user_id = 0 and updates it with every insert/replace query"...... Maybe you should use another value for `:user_id` ?

Comment: @arkascha It is a phpMyAdmin and I did not specify any settings, they are default, I think.

Comment: @Luuk I use. If insert a row with user_id 1, 2 or any another value it insert my row and row with user_id = 0. It will update anoter columns with data which I insert in last query.

Comment: *when I insert a new row into the table it inserts a row with user_id = 0 and updates it with every insert/replace query.* Does this means that the value provided for `user_id` column is ignored? If so then look does some triggers exists over this table...

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sessions`?  (Please use [edit] to add the info to your question!)

Comment: It really looks like the definition on your "real host" is different than the one you posted here. (or it has to do with triggers, like @Akina said)

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is NOT a DMBS, it is a _frontend_ used to interat with a RDBMS, namely a MySQL server. So what server do you use and what are its settings?